# How to find the Entry Assembly in a Lib when hosted in console or ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had the following code in v4.n of the .NET framework

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the Entry Assembly for both windows or ASP.NET
    /// runtimes
    /// </summary>
    private static Assembly GetEntryAssembly()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null ||
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance == null)
        {
            return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        }

        var type = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType();
        while (type != null && type.Namespace == "ASP")
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
        }

        return type == null ? null : type.Assembly;
    }
```

This ran fine and meant that it could be utilised from both console/exe and an ASP.NET application.

We are now porting code over to .NET Core (Standard) and now the HttpContext.Current has been removed in favour of automatic dependency injection.

However, this would then mean that simple lib that only wanted to know about the entry assembly would suddenly have to know about IHttpContextAccessor. This would definitely be a code smell!

In the new .Core world what is the best way of replacing this functionality?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()) for this purpose.

Comment: So this works consistently across both Asp.net apps and console/exes, in the old framework, this is not the case. As you can see previously I had to write special case code for asp.net?

Comment: Yes it should work consistently. In ASP.NET Core a web app is essentially just a console application, hence the `Program.Main` entry point, etc.

Comment: Thanks Henk, appreciate your response :)